# CMake install TARGETS with a target depending on Boost::statechart

Tags: boost, cmake, build

I am trying to compile some code that depends on Boost.Statechart library.

The following is my ***CMakeLists.txt*** file:

```
add_library(infrastructure_obj OBJECT
    infrastructure.cpp
)
target_compile_options(infrastructure_obj
    PRIVATE ${DEFAULT_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS}
    PRIVATE ${DEFAULT_CXX_OPTIMIZE_FLAG}
)
target_include_directories(infrastructure_obj INTERFACE
    "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>"
    "$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>"
)
set_target_properties(infrastructure_obj PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER src/infrastructure/include/infrastructure/infrastructure.h
    POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE 1
)
target_link_libraries(infrastructure_obj PRIVATE precompiled Boost::statechart)
BuildInfo(infrastructure_obj)

add_library(infrastructure_shared SHARED)
target_link_libraries(infrastructure_shared infrastructure_obj)
add_library(infrastructure_static STATIC)
target_link_libraries(infrastructure_static infrastructure_obj)

include(Coverage)
CleanCoverage(infrastructure_static)
include(Format)
Format(infrastructure_static .)
include(CppCheck)
AddCppCheck(infrastructure_obj)
include(Doxygen)
Doxygen(infrastructure src/infrastructure)
```

As you can see I have linked against the library in `target_link_libraries(infrastructure_obj PRIVATE precompiled Boost::statechart)`.

The following is my ***install.cmake*** file:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(BOOST_TARGETS boost_statechart boost_assert boost_bind boost_config
    boost_conversion boost_core boost_detail boost_function boost_mpl
    boost_smart_ptr boost_static_assert boost_thread boost_type_traits
    boost_throw_exception boost_typeof boost_integer boost_type_index
    boost_atomic boost_chrono boost_concept_check boost_container
    boost_container_hash boost_date_time boost_exception boost_intrusive
    boost_io boost_iterator boost_move boost_optional boost_predef
    boost_preprocessor boost_system boost_tuple boost_utility boost_winapi
    boost_algorithm boost_lexical_cast boost_align boost_ratio
    boost_describe boost_mp11 boost_numeric_conversion boost_functional
    boost_tokenizer boost_function_types boost_fusion boost_variant2
    boost_regex boost_unordered boost_array boost_range boost_rational
)
install(TARGETS ${BOOST_TARGETS} precompiled infrastructure_obj infrastructure_shared infrastructure_static
    EXPORT InfrastructureLibrary
    ARCHIVE COMPONENT infrastructure_dev
    LIBRARY COMPONENT infrastructure
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/infrastructure
        COMPONENT infrastructure
)
 
if(UNIX)
    install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ldconfig)"
        COMPONENT infrastructure
    )
endif()

install(EXPORT InfrastructureLibrary
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${MY_PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
    NAMESPACE ${MY_PACKAGE_NAME}::Infrastructure::
    COMPONENT infrastructure
)

install(FILES "ProjectConfig.cmake"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}/cmake
    RENAME "${MY_PACKAGE_NAME}Config.cmake"
)
```

Without having `${BOOST_TARGETS}` I get the following error:

> [cmake] CMake Error: install(EXPORT "InfrastructureLibrary" ...) includes target "infrastructure_obj" which requires target "boost_statechart" that is not in any export set.

Is there a better way than finding and adding all boost dependancies by hand to the `install(TARGETS...` command?

The complete project is at [here](https://github.com/MhmRhm/StateBench).